# String.split() called on a String contained in another array not working correctly

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, split

I am trying to obtain an array of `String`s (`dummy`) which is to be converted to a custom object Combo, by splitting every `String` contained in a second array (`readarray`). This second array is obtained by splitting the contents of a file.
Even though the array obtained by splitting the file's contents seems to be working fine, I can't seem to successfully split the `String`s it contains, I get one empty return (`dummy[0]`) and the ones after are `null`. Also,  `readFromFile()` simply uses a `FileInputStream` to return the full `String` the file contains.

```java
ArrayList<Combo> combos=new ArrayList<>();
String[] dummy;
String read=readFromFile();
String[] readarray=read.split("#");
for (String ss:readarray) {
    dummy=ss.split("-");
    Combo combo=new Combo(dummy[0],Integer.parseInt(dummy[1]),Integer.parseInt(dummy[2]),Integer.parseInt(dummy[3]));
    combos.add(combo);
}
```

This is the String the file contains from which the above reads:

> #22/09/2020-0900-2300-30#22/09/2020-0930-2330-30#22/09/2020-0900-2300-15

Help would be very much appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

remove the # from the beginning or the end of your string and you are fine.
because it will create the first empty object in your array.

Comment: Looks like i shouldn't write a comment saying "thanks", but, thanks. I spent so much time on this while knowing it had to be something simple, thanks a lot.